# SSH Local Port forwarding working from localhost only

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, rhel6

I can directly access `Host A ( 10.100.64.112)` from my `HomePC`  but cannot directly access `Host B (172.88.3.31)` . To access `Host B` , I need to first ssh to `Host A` and then to `Host B` .

To directly access `Host B` , I tried to set up an SSH tunnel using local port forwarding with the below command on `Host A`

```
 Host A # ssh  bzaman@10.100.64.112 -L 4420:172.88.3.31:22
```

Now I tried to validate whether the tunnel is working or not

```
 Host A # ssh 10.100.64.112 -p 4420
 bzaman@10.100.64.1121's password:
```

It works fine and it takes me to `Host B`

But If I access directly the tunnel from my `HOmePC` , it does not work

```
    $  ssh 10.100.64.112 -p 4122
    ssh: connect to host 10.100.64.112 port 4122: Connection refused
```

On checking with `netstat` , it shows the following

```
$ sudo netstat -an | grep 4420
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4420              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:4420                    :::*                        LISTEN
```

Please suggest so that I connect to `Host B` directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you aware that you type 4122 in the example?

You should try

```
-L *:4420:172.88.3.31:22
```

The star implies that you listen on all addresses, and not localhost, which you cannot connect to from other machines.

You can also bind to a specific IP, but my guess is that * is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

- [Martin's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/910550/488539) should work.

  - `-L *:4420:172.88.3.31:22`
  - or `-L 0.0.0.0:4420:172.88.3.31:22`
  - or `-L [specific IP]:4420:172.88.3.31:22`
- Another way:

  - `-L -g 4420:172.88.3.31:22`
  - Referenced from `man ssh`

    > -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.  If used on a multiplexed connection, then this option must be specified on the master process.